# Use Arduino GSM/GPRS shield to send data to from my web service to arduino and display it on Dot matrix Display

Tags: arduino, gsm, gprs, dmd

I want to ask how to control the Dot Matrix Display (DMD) via a web service that I created using GPRS shield v2.0 and Arduino Uno R3,,,

example: I filled out the information on a domain (mydomain.com/set?string = hello word) and will appear in DMD

than is that possible if the data from the twitter too?? so it can receive data from two source, there are from mydomain.com and twitter.com

I have:

- GPRS shield v2.0 which I bought from seeedstudio.com
- Using the Arduino Uno R3
- DMD 16X32 that I bought from freetronics

Answer (score 2):

Hope this works :)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial gprsSerial(7, 8);

void setup()
{
  gprsSerial.begin(19200);
  Serial.begin(19200);

  Serial.println("Config SIM900...");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Done!...");
  gprsSerial.flush();
  Serial.flush();

  // attach or detach from GPRS service 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CGATT?");
  delay(100);
  toSerial();


  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();

  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"epc.tmobile.com\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();

  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();
}


void loop()
{
   // initialize http service
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
   delay(2000); 
   toSerial();

   // set http param value
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://YOUR.DOMAIN.COM/rest/receiveSensorData?sensorval1=blah&sensorval2=blah\"");
   delay(2000);
   toSerial();

   // set http action type 0 = GET, 1 = POST, 2 = HEAD
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
   delay(6000);
   toSerial();

   // read server response
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPREAD"); 
   delay(1000);
   toSerial();

   gprsSerial.println("");
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPTERM");
   toSerial();
   delay(300);

   gprsSerial.println("");
   delay(10000);
}

void toSerial()
{
  while(gprsSerial.available()!=0)
  {
    Serial.write(gprsSerial.read());
  }
```

}

Comment: reference with the code above, how can i know if there are connect through internet?? i mean what is the output of that code??? is that serial software like hyperterminal???

But thank you about your answer for my question,, really help :)